# Marshalling variable size array in a struct

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm wrapping some old C++ code into C# and I've hit a snag. I have the following structures:

In C++:

```cpp
typedef struct tagEIPCIPTAGDBACCESS
{
    char * tagName;

    WORD   opType;

    DWORD  daType;
    DWORD  eleSize;
    DWORD  numEle;

    void * data  ;
    void * wrMask;

    int    result;
} EIPCIPTAGDBACCESS;
```

and in C# I have built it as:

```cs
public unsafe struct EIPCIPTAGDBACCESS
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string tagName;                 

    public short opType;                  

    public uint daType;       
    public uint eleSize;
    public uint numEle;      
        
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)]
    public byte [] data;                  
    public UIntPtr wrMask;                 

    public int result;
}
```

I can't access the original function because I'm using a library from ages ago.  However, I have some example code written 15 years ago that kind of works which I can show calling this function:

```
//Before this snip are 150 lines of code where variables are initialized and established.
//All references to the relevant variables are used below in their entirety 
<snip>
DWORD  numTagEle = calcNumEle(tagInfo.xDim, tagInfo.yDim, tagInfo.zDim);
            void * pData;

            if ( numTagEle == 0 )
            {
                printf("! Tag has no elements?\n");
            }
            else if ( (pData = malloc(numTagEle * tagInfo.eleSize)) == NULL )
            {
                printf("! Unable to allocate tag data memory!, size=%lu\n", numTagEle * tagInfo.eleSize);
            }
            else
            {
                EIPCIPTAGDBACCESS   ta;
                EIPCIPTAGDBACCESS * pTa[1];

                ta.tagName = tagName;                       // Setup read request
                ta.daType = tagInfo.daType;
                ta.eleSize = tagInfo.eleSize;
                ta.opType = EIP_CIP_TAG_READ_OP;
                ta.numEle = numTagEle;
                ta.data = pData;
                ta.wrMask = NULL;
                ta.result = OCX_ERR_NOINIT;
                pTa[0] = &ta;

                memset(pData, 0x0A, ta.numEle * ta.eleSize);
                                                            // Access tag as a whole
                if ( (rc = EIPcip_AccessTagDataDb(hApi, hTagDb, pTa, 1, NULL)) != OCX_SUCCESS )
                {
                    printf("! EIPcip_AccessTagDataDb() err=[%s]\n", ocxErrStr(rc, errStr));
                }
                else if ( ta.result != OCX_SUCCESS )
                {
                    printf("! EIPcip_AccessTagDataDb() result=[%s] name=[%s] daType=%lXh\n"
                          ,ocxErrStr(ta.result, errStr),
                           ta.tagName, ta.daType
                          );
                }
else                                        // If success, display value
                {
                    DWORD x, y, z;
                    char  tnBuff[256];

                    if ( tagInfo.xDim == 0 )
                    {
                        strcpy(tnBuff, tagName);
                        displayTagVal(hApi, hTagDb, tnBuff
                                     ,tagInfo.hStruct, tagInfo.daType, 0
                                     ,pData, 0, 0
                                     );
                    }
                    else if ( tagInfo.yDim == 0 )
                    {
                        for ( x = 0; x < tagInfo.xDim; x++)
                        {
                            sprintf(tnBuff, "%s[%lu]", tagName, x);
                            displayTagVal(hApi, hTagDb, tnBuff
                                         ,tagInfo.hStruct, tagInfo.daType, 0
                                         ,pData, x * tagInfo.eleSize, 0
                                         );
                        }
                    }
                    else if ( tagInfo.zDim == 0 )
                    {
                        for ( x = 0; x < tagInfo.xDim; x++ )
                        {
                            for ( y = 0; y < tagInfo.yDim; y++ )
                            {
                                sprintf(tnBuff, "%s[%lu,%lu]", tagName, x, y);
                                displayTagVal(hApi, hTagDb, tnBuff
                                             ,tagInfo.hStruct, tagInfo.daType, 0
                                             ,pData, (x * tagInfo.yDim * tagInfo.eleSize)+(y * tagInfo.eleSize), 0
                                             );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for ( x = 0; x < tagInfo.xDim; x++ )
                        {
                            for ( y = 0; y < tagInfo.yDim; y++ )
                            {
                                for ( z = 0; z < tagInfo.zDim; z++ )
                                {
                                    sprintf(tnBuff, "%s[%lu,%lu,%lu]", tagName, x, y, z);
                                    displayTagVal(hApi, hTagDb, tnBuff
                                                 ,tagInfo.hStruct, tagInfo.daType, 0
                                                 ,pData
                                                 ,  (x * tagInfo.yDim * tagInfo.zDim * tagInfo.eleSize)
                                                   +(y * tagInfo.zDim * tagInfo.eleSize)
                                                   +(z * tagInfo.eleSize)
                                                 ,0
                                                 );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                free(pData);
<snip>
```

The problem is data. It's a variable size array and the number of elements it contains can be found in the `numEle` variable.
When calling a function, you can marshal arrays like this with a `SizeParamIndex` and it allocates the right amount of memory for you. I'd like to do something similar, but with the instance itself, so I can use `Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr)` to bring it into managed memory. Is there some way I can achieve this effect?

Comment: You do not have a `ByValArray`. You have an [`LPArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=net-5.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_UnmanagedType_LPArray), for which you do not need to specify a size. `tagName` is also very not `BStr`, it is `LPStr`.

Comment: It is not a ByValArray.  You need to declare the field as IntPtr and marshal the data yourself with Marshal.Copy().  And worry a good deal about what you need to do to release the storage for that data, we can't tell when you don't post equivalent C code.

Comment: @GSerg If I specify it as an LPString, tagname comes back as a single unicode character 2.  If I specify BStr, it reads properly.  As for the array, if I declare it an LPArray I get the following  somewhat cryptic error: "Cannot marshal field 'data' of type 'TagReaderWrapper.EIPCIPTAGDBACCESS': This type can only be marshaled in restricted ways."

Comment: @Raligan Programming by trial and error is not helpful, and can have some long term dear consequences when it produces a seemingly correct result by coincidence. Please show the function that accepts this structure in C++ and how you call it from C#.

Comment: @HansPassant That works!  I've tried a number of combinations of things but I'd never considered that- I can just marshal the byte array in code when I need it.  Thanks for the help- I'll upvote/accept an answer if you leave one.  As for the allocing the data, I was trying to pass it in from managed memory with pinned bytes but this sheds light on the proper way.  I will Marshal.AllocHGlobal and .Free the memory from within the C# code.

Comment: @GSerg I can't show you the function because it's in a black box, and there's no documentation beyond the header file and inline comments.  I have some 15 year old trial and error example code that I've included if that helps.

Comment: The header file and the inline comments would be fine. This code calling it is not really helpful. Your C# code would also help.